# Is there any known correlation between stomach worms and fungal skin infections?

Tags: dermatology, gastroenterology, fungal-infection, ringworm, hookworm

Is there any literature which points to correlation between worm infestation of the intestines and fungal infection of the skin?

The possible mechanism being the stomach worms [disrupting](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12561678/) natural topical ecosystem by altering IgE levels and causing allergic reations which could make skin more vulnerable to fungal infections.

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Comment: @CareyGregory I couldn't find any, apart from worm casuing allergic skin conditions. Here's another paper talking about it https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3194028/